# C: Shell command double output without reason

Tags: c, fgets, can-bus

so im working with CAN utils
using [this](https://github.com/CANopenNode/CANopenSocket) CANopenNode
im making candump through a .c program file.

my code for the receiver looks like this

```
char raw_message[47], message_id[4], message_data[17];
fp = popen("candump vcan0 -L", "r");

  if( fp == NULL )
  {
    printf("Failed to run CANDUMP for VCAN0");
    exit(1);
  }

  while ( fgets(raw_message, sizeof(raw_message), fp) )
  {
      if( isspace(raw_message[0]) )
      {
      }
      else
      {
        //GETTING THE ACTUAL MESSAGE = ID+DATA
        cid = 0;
        cdata = 0;
        for(i=26; i<46; i++)
        {
          if( i<29 )
          {
            message_id[cid] = raw_message[i];
            cid++;
          }
          else if ( i==29 )
            message_id[cid] = '\0';
          else if ( i>29 )
          {
            message_data[cdata] = raw_message[i];
            cdata++;
          }
        }
        message_data[16] = '\0';
        //END OF GETTING MESSAGE
        fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",raw_message); 
        fflush(stdout);
      }

  }

  pclose(fp);
```

and im running a shell script for sending

```
echo "Start"
i=0;
while [ $i -le 5 ] ;
do
    #echo "sent"
    cansend vcan0 123#0801010101010101
    let i=$i+1
done
exit 0
```

what im trying to do is to split the id from the actual data of message. The thing is that as you can see I do that only if the first slot of the raw_message isnt space cause I receive a message i get it with fgets and then I get '        ' then message, then '       ' and so go on. Only when I use if (isspace) seems to work and if I put on comments the command "fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",raw_message);" stops working.
I tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to work. Is there any particular reason why is doing that? Am I doing something wrong or it maybe something of CANUtils ?

Output when I use issspace() (output is the same as when I run candump on bash){}

```
(1585149182.549347) vcan0 123#0801010101010101
(1585149182.550713) vcan0 123#0801010101010101
(1585149182.555930) vcan0 123#0801010101010101
(1585149182.559413) vcan0 123#0801010101010101
(1585149182.560687) vcan0 123#0801010101010101
(1585149182.561604) vcan0 123#0801010101010101
```

Output when I dont use it

```
while ( fgets(raw_message, sizeof(raw_message), fpdump) )
  {
      // if( isspace(raw_message[0]) )
      // {
      // }
      // else
      {
        //GETTING THE ACTUAL MESSAGE = ID+DATA
        cid = 0;
        cdata = 0;
        for(i=26; i<46; i++)
        {
          if( i<29 )
          {
            message_id[cid] = raw_message[i];
            cid++;
          }
          else if ( i==29 )
            message_id[cid] = '\0';
          else if ( i>29 )
          {
            message_data[cdata] = raw_message[i];
            cdata++;
          }
        }
        message_data[16] = '\0';
        //END OF GETTING MESSAGE
        fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",raw_message); 
        fflush(stdout);
      }

  }
```

Output:

```
(1585149305.257591) vcan0 123#0801010101010101


(1585149305.258339) vcan0 123#0801010101010101


(1585149305.259055) vcan0 123#0801010101010101


(1585149305.259651) vcan0 123#0801010101010101


(1585149305.260280) vcan0 123#0801010101010101


(1585149305.260860) vcan0 123#0801010101010101
```

Comment: Do you actually get the raw data as a text string of binary digits? That's a very strange API if that's the case.

Comment: no im getting a format of 123#0801010101010101

Comment: Then why do you check if i<29? And what's what in that format, is it hex, decimal...? What's the # for?

Comment: decimal, "#" splits id of message and data of the message

Comment: Then your code isn't the slightest related to that input string... just use `strtol` and a pointer.

Comment: @KyleeHolcomb Please add all information to your question instead of answering in comments. Please show a few lines of example output of `candump vcan0 -L`. I think you should better use the socketcan interface instead of parsing the output of `candump`. Using `popen` is problematic.

Comment: this is the actual ouput and i wanna get the last word (1585146534.509701) vcan0 123#0801010101010101

Comment: @KyleeHolcomb **Please [edit] your question** and add all information there. Show a few lines of the command output.

Comment: Please (also) show the output of `candump vcan0 -L` without using your program.

Comment: output is the same as when I use isspace

Comment: Please show the definition of `raw_message`. I guess it is not big enough for the output including the trailing newline. In this case one call will return a line of text without the newline because the buffer is full and the next call will return the newline only. As I already mentioned, it would be better to use the socketcan interface instead of parsing the output of a tool that is intended for manual inspection of CAN data. The additional newlines are inserted by your `fprintf` format string. If you remove the `\n` you won't see empty lines in the output, but still get the same data.

Comment: char raw_message[47], message_id[4], message_data[17];

Comment: As I have seen socketcan interface works the same way what would be the difference ?

Comment: What should your code do? What should the output be? You want to get `123#0801010101010101`? Ie. you want `printf("%s\n", strrchr(raw_message, ' '));`?

Comment: What do you mean with "socketcan interface works the same way"? With socketcan you open a socket, bind it to the CAN interface and read the CAN message as binary data. You don't have to parse the text output of a command line tool.

Comment: See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/can.html

Comment: As I already guessed, `raw_message` must have a size of at least 48 to hold a complete line including `'\n'` and `'\0'`.

Comment: @Bodo SocketCan works as what im using. I just parse the candump data to collect the id and the actual data of the message

Comment: @KyleeHolcomb If you look at the socketcan description I already referenced in my comment and answer you would see that this API is completely different from your parsing of text data. (Of course you will also get the CAN message ID and data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example data as shown in the question

```
(1585149182.549347) vcan0 123#0801010101010101
(1585149182.550713) vcan0 123#0801010101010101
```

...

has a line length of 46 characters without the newline character (`'\n'`) or 47 including the newline.

`fgets` needs to append a trailing `NUL` character (`'\0'`)  to terminate the string. That's why the first call will read the line without the newline because the buffer is full. The buffer will contain the string

```
"(1585149182.549347) vcan0 123#0801010101010101"
```

The next call will read the newline character only because this is the end of the line. The buffer will contain

```
"\n"
```

You have to increase the size of `raw_message` to at least 48.
Then you would get

```
"(1585149182.549347) vcan0 123#0801010101010101\n"
```

in one `fgets` call.

Note that it might be better to read the binary CAN messages using the [socketcan interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/can.html) instead of parsing the text output of `candump`.

Comment: Thank you that was the reason but one more thing. While when I remove fprintf of raw_message it stops working ?

Comment: I mean I want to edit raw_message and continue to next message without display it

Comment: @KyleeHolcomb Please **write a new question**. Show the code you are using when it works and show the modification. What exactly means "it stops working"? What do you expect and what happens instead or doesn't happen as expected? What do you mean with "I want to edit raw_message"? Write enough details in your question. You can write a link to the new question in a comment here.

Comment: @Bobo I would but I have reached the limit. If I remove fprintf(stdout,"%s",raw_message) while loop runs forever

Comment: @KyleeHolcomb Is there a limit for new questions? The loop will run forever because your `candump` command runs forever. You could use option `-n` to specify a number of CAN messages after which you want it to stop.